# timer not stopped in asp.net after timer disabled in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, timer

I set the timer in `ASP.NET` web page. Then I disabled the timer after completing the process, but timer is still running.

```
static bool _end;
protected void UpdateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_end)
    {
        _end = false;                     
        UpdateTimer.Enabled = false;                    
        Download();
    }
}
```

This is click event:

```
protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    StringBuilder threadBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    ProgressBar1.Visible = true;
    pReadytoDown.Visible = true;
    _end = false;
    Progress progress = ProgressBar1.Progress;

    Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
        _end= Start(progress);
        _builder = threadBuilder;
    });
    thread.Start();
}
```

This is Download file fun:

```
public void Download()
{
    string path = Server.MapPath("~/") + "ExcelFiles\\Sample.xlsx";
    Response.ClearContent();
    //context.Response.ClearHeaders();       
    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ExportData1.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xlsx";
    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
    return;
}
```

Comment: are you sure that `_end == true` once? Why do you want the timer at all?  `Download` sounds like something the *client* should do but of course the timer (what kind of timer is this?) will run on the server.

Comment: Additionally I **highly** suspect that you create the timer each time the page get created (in the constructor) so this will never work ... overall: don't do stateful things on web-code-behind-files - **ASP.NET 101** ;)

Comment: btw: why the `ajax` tag? - is this one of those `ajax timers`? - Please give us some more details - thanks

Comment: yes, _end is true when process completed such as thread returns _end==true. i wants to write the data into excel after exported the file that file will automatically download. i'm not able to find thread finish the work or not. so it return end==true.

Comment: yes, yes  it's a ajax timer pro.

Comment: to be honest: I have no clue how this really works as I stopped using WebForms (very) long ago but I still suspect that something like `_end` will just be recreated on each loop - so can you add some more of your code - for example where you define and initialize  `_end`, etc.?

Comment: ok pro just wait... i place the code

Comment: for click event protected void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            StringBuilder threadBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            ProgressBar1.Visible = true;
            pReadytoDown.Visible = true;
            _end = false;
            Progress progress = ProgressBar1.Progress;
            
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                _end= Start(progress);
                _builder = threadBuilder;
                
            });
            thread.Start();
           }

Comment: that's basically the same - also please edit it into your question - thanks

Comment: i'm not able to paste all the code in comment i just edit my question

Comment: yep just as I thought - that's the horrible client/server mix you get from WebForms - still wher do you declare the variables - see if you do just `private bool _end = false` then you already lost - but if you get it from the session-variable or something ... well you see

Comment: i declared like : static bool _end; in Global

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
     if(IsPostBack)
                {
//first time timer1 has default value as 60000 = 1 sec then 2nd time it value will be 10 min
                    timer1.Interval = 600000; 
                    ViewState["countet"] = 600000;
                }
```